# How can I estimate uncertainty for a small sample of proportion data?

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, bootstrap, standard-error, uncertainty

I'm not an expert on this topic. I'm working on a poster for a conference. I need to plot SEMs, confidence intervals, or some measure of uncertainty around a measure of central tendency (e.g., median). I have small samples, n = 6, of proportion data. First, I plotted error bars with the SEMs, but I noticed that the error bars could exceed the limits of the binomial distribution (e.g., position < 0 or > 1). This is certainly awkward. So I secondly opted to work with bootstrap techniques. Maybe I could use 68% confidence intervals to substitute the first intended SEMs. I thought that this would be  a good idea, given that confidence intervals of a bootstrapped distribution might be assymetric, putatively solving the limit exceeding problem. However, I read that bootstrapping is not recomended for samples < 9. Is this an unbending rule, or may I proceed with caution to estimate uncertainty through bootstrapping? How can I estimate uncertainty otherwise?

Comment: If you're using R, you can do this to get a 95% confidence interval: binom.test(positives, sample.size, conf.level=.95)$conf.int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When N is small the standard measures don't work well for proportions. There's actually quite a large literature on this.  A good entry point is [Agresti and Coull](http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/articles/agresti_coull_1998.pdf) *Approximate is Better than Exact for Interval Measure of Binomial Proportions*.  They offer several methods to deal with this problem, but the simplest is to add 2 "successes" and 2 "failures" to the data and proceed as usual.

R and SAS both offer several choices to do this estimation. Other statistical packages may do so, as well.